# RxJs iif() operator is not subscribing to provided observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, switchmap

With the following code I'm intending to subscribe to `function1`, and then depending on the result (saleAgreed), subscribe to a second observable; either `function2` or `of(undefined)`. See below:

```js
this.apiService.function1(id).pipe(
        switchMap(async (saleAgreed: boolean) => {

          // Wait for some input from the user
          let cancelAgreedSale = await this.promptSaleAgreedCancelDetails();

          // These are both evaluating to true   
          console.log(`sale agreed: ${saleAgreed}`)
          console.log(`cancelSaleAgreed: ${cancelAgreedSale}`)

          iif(
            function() {
              if (saleAgreed && cancelAgreedSale) { 
                this.removeSaleAgreedRequest = { 
                  contactId : this.cid, 
                  details : this.cancelSaleAgreedDetails
                };
              }
              return saleAgreed && cancelAgreedSale;
            }, this.apiService.function2(this.removeSaleAgreedRequest), of(undefined));

          // Thought returning the observable might help, but doesn't make a difference whether 
          // it's here or not
          return this.apiService.function2(this.removeSaleAgreedRequest)
        })
      ).subscribe(res => { 
        // Returns either undefined or an observable if I return one above
        console.log(res)
      }, error => { 
        console.log(error.error)
      })
```

`function2` implementation:

```
public function2(request: RemoveSaleAgreedRequest): Observable<any>  { 
    console.log('api func hit!')
    return this.http.patch<any>(this.apiUrl + 'some/endpoint', request);
  }
```

It's my understanding that my code should evaluate the result of the anonymous function I provide to `iif()`. If it evaluates to true, function2 should be subscribed to, otherwise it should subscribe to `of(undefined)`. `function1` is subscribed to fine, however even though my anonymous function is evaluating to true, `function2` is not being subscribed to. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just call the `iif` operator like a function. `iif` returns an `Observable` which needs to be subscribed, ideally by an operator within your pipe.

Marking the callback as `async` will (probably) also cause problems. I don't think returning an `Observable` wrapped inside a `Promise` will be properly handled by RxJS. Mixing `async` and Observables is often not necessary. Let's wrap the call to `this.promptSaleAgreedCancelDetails()` into a `from()`.

We can process result of `this.promptSaleAgreedCancelDetails()` in a `switchMap`. This `switchMap` logs the two variables and uses a normal `if`/`else` to handle the logic.

```
this.apiService
  .function1(id)
  .pipe(
    switchMap((saleAgreed: boolean) => {
      return from(this.promptSaleAgreedCancelDetails()).pipe(
        switchMap((cancelAgreedSale) => {
          console.log(`sale agreed: ${saleAgreed}`);
          console.log(`cancelSaleAgreed: ${cancelAgreedSale}`);

          if (saleAgreed && cancelAgreedSale) {
            this.removeSaleAgreedRequest = {
              contactId: this.cid,
              details: this.cancelSaleAgreedDetails,
            };
            return this.apiService.function2(this.removeSaleAgreedRequest)
          } else {
            return of(undefined)
          }
        })
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe(
    (res) => console.log(res),
    (error) => console.log(error.error)
  );
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! I provided the async callback function in order to await input from the user - as `function2` depends on this input. If I change my code to what you've described here I get the error `Argument of type '() => Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => boolean'.` on my anon function. If I then change `this.promptSaleAgreedCancelDetails()` to not be async it removes the error but `cancelAgreedSale` will evaluate to false since the user has not given their input yet, and thus `function2` will not be called. Do you know of a way around this?

Comment: @Laurence - Can you try replacing `of()` with `from()` (check my edit)? And always remove the `async`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work unfortunately - for clarity `this.promptSaleAgreedCancelDetails()` remains an async function, but when switching to `from()`  `function2` isn't called.

Comment: What's the output of the two console.logs when using `from`?

Comment: `sale agreed: true
cancelSaleAgreed: true`

Comment: Ok, that's good. Does `apiService.function2` return an Obserable or a Promise?

Comment: Returns an Observable :) Also - when I changed `this.promptSaleAgreedCancelDetails()` to not be async in my first comment- that `function2` was hit perfectly fine, just not with the correct data, since it hadn't been taken from the user yet (not sure if that might help)

Comment: can you share the implementation of `function2`? How do you detect if it was called?

Comment: Also, see my last edit. It seems like you want to `defer` the call to `function2` until the `iif` is subscribed.

Comment: Have edited my OP with the implementation - I have a `console.log` inside that function, but more importantly I'm running the .net API locally - when it gets called correctly my breakpoint should be hit. `defer()` doesn't seem to make a difference also ^

Comment: I removed the `iif` and replaced it with a normal `if/else` for now. It should definitely call the function.

Comment: Yep, that's sorted it! Weird that iif() was having trouble but it does what I need it to now, thanks a lot for taking the time to go through this with me, much appreciated :)